# The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using code snippet to send message into the service bus topic.

```
        try
        {
            // sb is instance of ServiceBusConfig.GetServiceBusForChannel
            await sb.SendAsync(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(
                "chanel",
                "An error occurred while sending a notification: " + ex.Message,
                ex);
            throw;
        }
```

and implementation is

```
    public async Task SendAsync(BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        if (this.topicClient == null)
        {
            this.topicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(this.primaryConnectionString, this.topicPath);
            this.topicClient.RetryPolicy = this.retryPolicy;
        }

        await this.topicClient.SendAsync(message);
    }
```

Error:-

> "ErrorCode,12005,Message,""An error occurred while sending a
>   notification: The operation did not complete within the allotted
>   timeout of 00:01:00.  The time allotted to this operation may have
>   been a portion of a longer timeout. For more information on exception
>   types and proper exception handling,
>   Exception,""Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException:  The
>   operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00.
>   The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a
>   longer timeout.

For more information on exception types and proper exception handling

Comment: You are sure you are sending the message to the right service and that the service is accepting messages from outside?

Comment: yes.. this issue is happens sometimes not daily.

Comment: Does the message sometimes exceed the limit of 256KB ?

Comment: we are already validating size It won't accept more than 256 KB. It will through error message.

Comment: can anybody tell how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: What kind of volume do you have? Do you see any other error messages leading up to this?

Comment: We started seeing the same issue, did you find a solution? Is there a way to increase the timeout? @SudhirGoswami

Comment: Same here. We had an AZURE function running successfully, taking around 400k ms and then I changed the implementation and now this exception pops at around 200k ms. So I think it is not related to the function timeout but to a kind of operation timeout within the function.

Answer (score 2):

This happens occasionally.  Azure can change and shift their underlying hardware willy nilly.  These sort of errors pop up every now and then.  As long you have some appropriate retry logic where appropriate, the message will eventually get through ...