# Azure service bus "allotted timeout" exception

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have a console application registered to azure service bus that sometimes (not periodically, but random) show me the following error:

> The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:20. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout

And the following stack trace:

```
8-08-18 05:55:13.1251|ERROR|TestCefBrowserConsole.Workers.LinkWorkerThread|The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:20. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndUpdateCommand(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BatchManager`1.PerformFlushAsyncResult.OnFlushCompleted(IAsyncResult result, IList`1 batchedObjectsAsyncResults)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BatchManager`1.EndFlush(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BatchManager`1.EndBatchedOperation(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BatchManagerAsyncResult`1.OnBatchedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ReceiveContext.EndComplete(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at TestCefBrowserConsole.Workers.LinkWorkerThread.<<ListenOnQueueChange>b__5_1>d.MoveNext() in D:\Progetti\UrlTracker\TraceyClient\TestCefBrowserConsole\Workers\LinkWorkerThread.cs:line 76
```

And this stack trace is shown almost 20 times in the period of 1 minute (I'm using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) to log error on text file)

As you can see the last time in the stack trace suggest to check line 76 in LinkWorkerThread.cs. Here it is the code:

```cs
client.OnMessageAsync(async message =>
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("message from api");
        if (message.DeliveryCount > 2)
        {
            MaxDeliveryCountReached(message);
            await message.DeadLetterAsync();
         }
         else
         {
            try
            {
                await ProcessServiceBusMessage(message);
                await message.CompleteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errLog.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                await message.DeadLetterAsync();
            }
         }
    }, new OnMessageOptions() { AutoComplete = false, MaxConcurrentCalls = 20, AutoRenewTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0) });
```

Line 76 is `await message.CompleteAsync()`.

Why does the allotted timeout exception occur? How can I solve that? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653126/the-operation-did-not-complete-within-the-allotted-timeout-of-000100)

Comment: @Jayendran I found that question before publishing mine, but there wasn't a resolutive answer, then I made this question giving more details

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Please post the solution if you found any, I have similar issues